# Minimum swaps to relative sort two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`, we have to find the minimum swaps to relatively sort the two arrays into strictly increasing order. If relative sort is not possible, then -1 is returned.

The relative sort is defined as exchanging the same index element of `arr1` and `arr2`.

That is, steps for relative sort:

```
swap(arr1[i], arr2[i])
```

And strictly increasing order is defined as:

```
arr[i+1]>arr[i] for all i
```

Example:

```
arr1={1,4,4,9} 
arr2={2,3,5,10}
```

Then minimum swaps is 1, as interchanging `arr1[2]` and `arr2[2]`, will make both the arrays strictly increasing. 
I solved the question using recursion. 
If `arr[i]>arr[i+1]`, we can either swap elements at index `i` or elements at index `i+1`, and then call the function for index `i+1`. I tried to find the minimum of the two values and returned it. This procedure was followed for each index of `i`.

```
int f(int N, int *arr1, int *arr2, int i){
    if(i == N-1)
        return 0;
     if(arr1[i]>=arr1[i+1] && arr2[i]>=arr2[i+1])return -1;
    if(arr1[i]>=arr1[i+1] || arr2[i]>=arr2[i+1]){
        int m, n;
        swap(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
        m = f(N, arr1, arr2, i+1);
        swap(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
        swap(arr1[i+1, arr2[i+1]);
        n = f(N, arr1, arr2, i+1);
        if(m == -1 && n==-1)return -1;
        if(m==-1)return n;
        if(n==-1)return m;
        return min(m, n);
    }
    return f(N, arr1, arr2, i+1);
 }

int minSwaps(int N, int *arr1, int *arr2){
    return f(N, arr1, arr2, 0);
}
```

As this was a question I faced in an online coding test, I got the basic test cases passed, but I am still not sure whether this method would work for all test cases.

Also, I wonder if this question can be solved using dynamic programming. If yes, what state should be stored in table? And what should be the approach?

Comment: @LAD No, it's not. I am editing the question to include an exampe

Comment: Yeah, if you add the code you used, that would help readers a bit.

Comment: If I understand correctly, both arrays have to be in increasing order with no repetition of numbers and you need the minimum swaps to do that.

Comment: Yes, but along with this, we have to keep in mind that this can be done only by interchanging elements at the same index in both arrays.

Comment: And yes, i will be adding code i used too, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Oh! It's ok! And yes, I have added my code now

Comment: @Nisha Can we assume that relative sort is always possible from the given input? Like, what if 2 arrays are `[4,4,4]` and `[5,5,5]` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 Maybe the arrays can only have at most two repeating digits. I don't know the specifics, though, that's just a guess.

Comment: If relative sort is not possible, then we have to return - 1

Comment: @LAD ya, the OP needs to put more light on this. Even with atmost 2 repeating integers, there can be impossible states. Like `[1,5,9]` and `[2,3,3]`. I also feel that let's assume if only valid inputs are given, then this problem isn't as tricky as it seems.

Comment: @Nisha That makes sense. You might want to state that in the post.

Comment: @Nisha oh ok, let me see.

Comment: @Nisha are arrays individually sorted in the first place?

Comment: No it's not necessary to be sorted already

Comment: @Nisha so, if we individually sort them and apply relative sort on them, is it ok or we can't change their order?

Comment: I think we can't channge the order

Comment: @Nisha so for every location, we swap or we don't swap keeping an additional check of valid state. I feel this relates to mini-max algorithm

Answer (score 2):

```
int minSwap(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b){
    int inf = (int)(1e9);
    int n=a.size();
    int dp[n][2];
    dp[0][0]=0;
    dp[0][1]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        dp[i][0]=dp[i][1]=inf;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i-1]<a[i]&&b[i-1]<b[i]){
            dp[i][0]=dp[i-1][0];
            dp[i][1]=dp[i-1][1]+1;
        }
        if(a[i-1]<b[i]&&b[i-1]<a[i]){
            dp[i][0]=min(dp[i][0],dp[i-1][1]);
            dp[i][1]=min(dp[i][1],dp[i-1][0]+1);
        }
    }
    return min(dp[n-1][0],dp[n-1][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is exponential in the size of array. As you have noticed in your question, the solution can be obtained using dynamic programming.

First, let's define a helper function that checks whether after we swap `i-th and/or i + 1-st` element we obtain a locally valid solution. What I mean by locally valid is only considering these four numbers.

```
def isValid(i, preSwap, postSwap):
  val lx = if (preSwap) y(i) else x(i)
  val rx = if (postSwap) y(i + 1) else x(i + 1)
  val ly = if (preSwap) x(i) else y(i)
  val ry = if (postSwap) x(i + 1) else y(i + 1)
  // x(i) < x(i + 1) && y(i) < y(i + 1)
  lx < rx && ly < ry
```

Now, we will simply loop backwards the array. Our dynamic programming memory would be constant - we have to remember just two integers. Let's consider `i-th` iteration for `i = x.length - 2 downto 0`.

- what is the optimal number of swaps so that indicies `i + 1 upto x.length - 1` are sorted increasingly and `x(i)` and `y(i)` are **not swapped**,
- what is the optimal number of swaps so that indicies `i + 1 upto x.length - 1` are sorted increasingly and `x(i)` and `y(i)` are **swapped**.

For a list of length `1` we obtain a tuple `(prevNoSwap, prevSwap) = (0, 1)`. Our loop step would consider four cases:

- we don't swap at `i` and we don't swap at `i + 1`; optimal: `prevNoSwap`,
- we swap at `i` and we don't swap at `i + 1`; optimal: `prevNoSwap + 1`,
- we don't swap at `i` and we swap at `i + 1`; optimal: `prevSwap`,
- we swap at `i` and we don't swap at `i + 1`; optimal: `prevSwap + 1`.

If given case creates valid solution we would consider it as a possible number  of steps. We group them by `swapping / not swapping` at `i` and take the minimum. We assume that any of these elements might become `Infinity` if the solution cannot be found in specific case.

After the loop we pick a minimum of two tuple values. Here's the rest of the pseudocode:

```
state = (0, 1)
for i in x.length - 2 downto 0
  noPreSwap, withPreSwap = [#INFINITY], [#INFINITY]

  if (isValid(i, preSwap = false, postSwap = false)) noPreSwap += state.left
  if (isValid(i, preSwap = false, postSwap = true)) noPreSwap += state.right
  if (isValid(i, preSwap = true, postSwap = true)) withPreSwap += state.right + 1
  if (isValid(i, preSwap = true, postSwap = false)) withPreSwap += state.right

  state = (noPreSwap.min(), withPreSwap.min())
return if state.min().isInfinity() -1 else state.min()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Although I understand most of the part, I have a confusion as I am not familiar with writing too sophisticated pseudocodes. Are no PreSwap and withPreSwap arrays here?